# RGB/BGR format in 2d and cube mapping

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have an Android application using native code written in C++.
I am using OpenGL to display, but the textures are generated by Java code as bitmaps. I pass the raw memory content of bitmaps to the function glTexImage2D() and found the following behavior:

- If I use GL_RGB format, then cube mapping shows correct colours, while 2d mapping shows red and blue swapped.
- If I use GL_BGR_EXT format, then it is reversed: the 2d mapping is correct, and cube mapping shows wrong colours.

The same memory content was passed in these cases to the function glTexImage2D().
Now it seems that I must use GL_RGB for cube mapping, but GL_BGR_EXT for 2d mapping to get correct colours.

Running exactly the same code on Linux (generating texture bitmaps by PangoCairo), there is no difference between 2d and cube mapping, as expected (I use GL_RGB and I have correct colours).

I don't understand this difference between mapping modes. I tried it with different pixel formats (RGBA8888 and RGB565), the result is the same.

The corresponding code is here:

- for cube mapping:

  ```
  static const GLuint GLTargets[] = {
     GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X,
     GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
     GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y,
     GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
     GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z,
     GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z
  };

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
     glTexImage2D(
        GLTargets[i],                       //  target
        0,                                  //  level
        myFormat,                           //  internal format
        myTarget[i]->GetWidth(),            //  width
        myTarget[i]->GetHeight(),           //  height
        0, myFormat, myPixelFormat,         //  border, external format, type
        myTarget[i]->GetPixelData()         //  pixels
     );
  }
  ```
- for 2d mapping:

  ```
  glTexImage2D(
      GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,           // target, level
      myFormat,                   // internal format
      myWidth, myHeight, 0,       // width, height, border
      myFormat, myPixelFormat,    // external format, type
      myTarget.GetPixelData()     // pixels
  );
  ```

Is it an Android-specific behavior, or a bug, or do I something wrong?

I tried it on some different Samsung devices with Android 4.2.2.

Thanx in advance

Gyorgy Kovesdi